# How to find if player surrounded enemy's cells

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I am making simple game. (A matrix where players can take cells(x,y), only one player on one cell, and they acquire new cells after the player before). Every player has a unique color. I am trying to find out if one player has surrounded cells of other users.  In which case all cells are going to change color. Is there any known algorithm for this problem, to check only when user plays a new move ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you take a look at a [flood fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), these are simple algorithms that searches from a start point and tries to fill the board. You would simply have to check if the fill algorithm can reach the end of the board or not.